# Validate email or mobile with regular expression

Tags: php, php-5.2

I have one form field. In that field it's possible for user to enter **EMAIL** or **MOBILE**. From a PHP page i got value. After that i want to check whether this is email id or mobile number. suppose `email` means i want to email success,suppose `mobile` means i want to show mobile success ,i think we have to write regular expression,but i don't know how to write regular expression for this problem?

```html
 <form action="#" method="POST" id="forgotForm">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email OR Mobile" id="email" name="email" value="" aria-required="true" required="" data-msg-required="Please enter your email">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope form-control-feedback"></span>
  </div>
  </form>

  home.php
  <?php
  $email=$_POST['email'];//here value it will come like 9986128658 or admin@gmail.com
  
  ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the input using `preg_match`

```
$email=$_POST['email'];

$emailPattern = '/^\w{2,}@\w{2,}\.\w{2,4}$/'; 
$mobilePattern ="/^[7-9][0-9]{9}$/"; 

if(preg_match($emailPattern, $email)){
    echo "Email Success!";
} else if(preg_match($mobilePattern, $email)){
    echo "Mobile Success!";
} else {
    echo "Invalid entry";
}
```

1. Checks for the valid email

   - Email should have atleast two words length say `aa@aa.aa`
   - TLD should have atleast 2 characters and maximum of 4 characters
   - To include domains like co.in, use - `/^\w{2,}@[\w\.]{2,}\.\w{2,4}$/`
2. Checks for the valid mobile

   - Mobile should have 10 characters length and should start either with 7 or 8 or 9, to remove that restriction, change the `$mobilePattern` to `/^[0-9]{10}$/`
3. If it is not valid email or mobile, it returns error message

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the value is a valid email address. If it is then you have an email, otherwise you can assume that it is a phone number:

```
$email = null;
$phone = null;

// The "email" field has been submitted
if (isset($_POST["email"])) {

    // If it is an email then set the email variable
    if (filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    }
    // If it is a number then set the phone variable
    else if (filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
        $phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "email", FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    }
}

if ($email !== null) {
    echo "Submitted email: {$email}";
}
if ($phone !== null) {
    echo "Submitted phone number: {$phone}";
}
```